# Angularjs - Incorrect json format under Content-Type-application/json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, firebug, splunk

**Purpose**: 
I (a javascript beginner) am trying to perform a Rest API call to a web-server (Splunk) get data of content-type json. Call is initiated by angularjs based webApp, the problematic code snippet is posted below. The problem is investigated using firebug and the response & header information is mentioned below.

**Angular Code Snippet**:

```
        $scope.onClickButton = function (button) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://localhost:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/search/jobs/export',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Authorization': 'Splunk ' + $scope.sessionKey
                },
                data: {search: button.query, output_mode: 'json'}
            }).success(function (response) {                    
                alert("Success"); 
            }).error(function (response) {
                alert("error");// alerted error
                alert(response); // alerts 'undefined'
            });
        };
```

**Response Object** (captured by firebug)

{"preview":false,"offset":0,"result":{"_serial":"0", "_sourcetype":"mylogger", "splunk_server":"mohit-PC"}}
{"preview":false,"offset":1,"result":{"_serial":"1", "_sourcetype":"mylogger", "splunk_server":"mohit-PC"}}
{"preview":false,"offset":2,"result":{"_serial":"2", "_sourcetype":"mylogger", "splunk_server":"mohit-PC"}}
...

**Response Header**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date    Tue, 02 Dec 2014 13:00:34 GMT
Expires Thu, 26 Oct 1978 00:00:00 GMT
Server  Splunkd
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Vary    Authorization
access-control-allow-cred...    true
x-content-type-options  nosniff
x-frame-options SAMEORIGIN
```

**Firebug Error**

Error: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data fromJson@angular.js:1054:9 
.

**Questions**

Q1. The status of response is - `200 OK`, then why the error is thrown? Though it is apparent that the response text does not represent a json object or an array of json objects. The [] and commas are absent. The server cannot be configured to respond with a proper formatted data. It seems angular does a format verification and throws exception. Can this verification be avoided/bypassed?

Q2. Even though the error occurred, why the response object is 'undefined' in http.error method? If it were not, I could do string manipulations as a work around.

Comment: Your response object doesn't seem right. You should have an array of objects in your case. Did you copy paste the whole thing?

Comment: @jValdron: Yes, I copied it. Each line represent a valid json, but the whole text does not represent the array-of-json, which I believe is the reason for error.

Comment: Yep, you should have something like this: `[{ ... }, { ... }, { ... }]`.

Comment: yes, I do acknowledge that this is format in which I am receiving the data. My focus is on doing a pre-processing before the error is thrown or any mechanism where the exception could be caught. I just found out the angular interceptor, which seems to provide such functionality. I am looking into it.